# Getting value from serialized wordpress meta data

Tags: php, wordpress, meta

I'm trying to use get_post_meta to grab some data that's being saved alongside my posts, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to unserialise and access the data. The data that's stored in the database is

```
a:8:{s:10:"headerType";s:5:"image";s:11:"headerImage";s:0:"";s:5:"dates";s:0:"";s:3:"fee";a:2:{i:0;a:4:{s:4:"name";s:11:"Basic Entry";s:5:"price";s:2:"50";s:3:"url";s:0:"";s:4:"desc";s:14:"This is great.";}i:1;a:4:{s:4:"name";s:8:"Megatron";s:5:"price";s:2:"20";s:3:"url";s:0:"";s:4:"desc";s:6:"Great.";}}s:8:"currency";s:3:"USD";s:4:"item";s:1:"0";s:15:"useItemLocation";s:2:"no";s:3:"map";a:7:{s:7:"address";s:0:"";s:8:"latitude";s:1:"0";s:9:"longitude";s:1:"0";s:10:"streetview";s:1:"0";s:9:"swheading";s:2:"90";s:7:"swpitch";s:1:"5";s:6:"swzoom";s:1:"1";}}
```

Which I can get by using this code:

```
$meta = get_post_meta($post_id, "", true);
$event_meta = $meta["_ait-event-pro_event-pro-data"];
```

And then what I'm trying is:

```
$formatted_event_meta = unserialize($event_meta);
echo $formatted_event_meta["fee"][0]["name"];
```

Hoping to get **Basic Entry** as the result, but no dice. This is part of a plugin so I'm not getting any errors that I can find to troubleshoot.

**EDIT:**

This meta information is being set here:

```
$relatedItem = $_POST['_ait-event-pro_event-pro-data']['item'];
update_post_meta( $post_id, 'ait-event-pro-related-item', $relatedItem );
```

Comment: BTW, in that data, `["fee"][0]["name"] == "Basic Entry"`. `["fee"][1]["name"] == "Megatron"`

Comment: Ah, thanks, you're right. Any other ideas where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Somewhere that isn't listed here. Because just by changing your echo to the correct reference I listed there, I was able to get the result you were after.

Comment: Is this meta being added using add_post_meta, or some other way?

Answer (score 0):

The issues were arising because this code to check the meta information was being executed as the post was being added, which meant most of the time they meta data hadn't been added yet.

Comment: Have you resolved it? If so, it would be good to get your final, working code in your answer for others that might come across a similar issue.